# How to make a method pop first in java fluent interface?

Tags: java, interface, field, fluent

This is my first asking, so sorry if I messed something.
I have a task to implement a Mail, using Java fluent interface. 
I must have fields: From, To, Subject.

The problem is, I can not make "From" to appear as first and only.
Example: 
MailBuilder builder = new MailBuilder();
builder.from("Stiliyan").to("Alexander").subject("Welcome aboard");

But when I type the first dot "." all of them appears. (eg builder.to("a").from("b")..)

So in short: builder.(HERE MUST APPEAR ONLY "from").to("No worries")..."

[Here is MailBuilder.java](https://pastebin.com/VrU7vdVQ)

[So here after "." must appear ONLY from method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DCr1.png)

Comment: Is the IDE showing? Or you have developed a text editor? If you are programming an IDE Plugin so you must have to look something about code completation suggestions.

Comment: It is just a console application. Nothing special, just to get used with fluent interface. So when I finish the task, he told me the from field must appear as first and only choice.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos I added the code in pastebin. Edited the question too.

Comment: If `from` is a required field, you can make it a parameter of the builder's constructor. Would that be OK?

Comment: @Bohemian no, because as first option it must show ONLY `from`, nothing else, except the implemented methods as toString, hashCode and etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then your **declared** return type of each of the builder methods cannot be the same. You can still return the same builder instance though. For example:

```
interface IFromBuilder {
    IToBuilder from(String from);
}

interface IToBuilder {
    IMailBuilder to(String to);
}

interface IMailBuilder {
    Mail build();
}

class MailBuilder implements IFromBuilder, IToBuilder, IMailBuilder {

    private String from;
    private String to;

    @Override
    public IToBuilder from(String from) {
        this.from = from;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public IMailBuilder to(String to) {
        this.to = to;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Mail build() {
        return new Mail(from, to);
    }
}

class Mail {
    private final String from;
    private final String to;

    public Mail(String from, String to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    public static IFromBuilder newBuilder() {
        return new MailBuilder();
    }
}


public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mail mail = Mail.newBuilder().from("sender@a.com").to("receiver@b.com").build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great Solution.

Comment: @Xinchao I marked your answer as Solution. It helped me a lot. Thank you !

Comment: I would like to ask you for a little bit more explanation. I reviewed all of the code but still can not understand what it makes `from` to pop out as first ?

Comment: That "pop up" is not something you implement but an IDE feature. It will largely depend on how a specific IDE works. It is generally beyond your control. But, all of IDEs will only show you the methods that can be legally invoked at that site, and this is something you can control - by making only one method legal at a time. The trick is the **declaration type** of the return value. The `Mail.newBuilder()` returns an `IFromBuilder`. And on the IFromBuilder interface there is only one method: `from (String)`. It is not that "from" pops out first, it is that "from" is the only method can pop out