# How to define an order for a fluent lambda passed to a method

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, fluent

In [this talk by venkat subramaniam](https://youtu.be/e4MT_OguDKg?t=2024) he makes the following Mailer example:

```java
class Mailer {
  public Mailer from(String addr) { System.out.println("from"); return this; }
  public Mailer to(String addr) { System.out.println("to"); return this; }
  public Mailer subject(String subjectLine) { System.out.println("subject"); return this; }
  public Mailer body(String message) { System.out.println("body"); return this; }
  public static void send(Consumer<Mailer> block) { 
    Mailer mailer = new Mailer();
    block.accept(mailer);
    System.out.println("sending..."); 
  }
}

public class Sample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Mailer.send(mailer -> {
      mailer.from("builder@agiledeveloper.com")
            .to("venkats@agiledeveloper.com")
            .subject("Your code sucks")
            .body("...");      
    });
  }
}
```

For this specific case I know the implementation details might not make sense as a mailer like this wouldn't care about the order, but if I wanted to force an order in which you call `from`, `to`, `subject`, and `body` such that you must start with `from`, then `to`, then `subject` then `body` how would I do this?

I did see the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099774/how-to-make-a-method-pop-first-in-java-fluent-interface) but this relies on starting the flow with the `newBuilder` method and I'm not sure how this pattern could be applied with the lambda example.

Comment: Why do you want to force such an order in the first place? Letting us know this might get you a more helpful answer.

Comment: Honestly I just wanted to know if it was possible. I was watching the talk linked and wondered how you could handle a forced flow with that pattern. Incase maybe there is a situation where you don't want to give the developer a "mailer" object to play with but you want them to build the "mailer" with some required settings that you don't want to set defaults for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it seems like the approach in the linked question doesn't quite apply here, it can be adapted a little bit to suit your purposes.

Let's first add the types shown in the linked question:

```
interface IFromBuilder {
    IToBuilder from(String from);
}

interface IToBuilder {
    ISubjectBuilder to(String to);
}

interface ISubjectBuilder {
    IBodyBuilder subject(String line);
}

interface IBodyBuilder {
    void body(String body);
}

class Mailer implements IFromBuilder, IToBuilder, ISubjectBuilder, IBodyBuilder {

    // implementations...
}
```

Instead of a `newBuilder` method, you are using a `send` method that accepts a `Consumer<Mailer>`. Instead of this, use a `Consumer<IFromBuilder>`

```
public static void send(Consumer<IFromBuilder> block) { 
    Mailer mailer = new Mailer();
    block.accept(mailer);
    System.out.println("sending..."); 
}
```

If you want to force developers to write the whole chain of methods every time, you can do this:

Make the last of your chain of methods return another type:

```
interface ICompletedMailer { // Mailer should also implement this

}

interface IBodyBuilder {
    ICompletedMailer body(String body);
}
```

And change the `Consumer<IFromBuilder>` to a `Function<IFromBuilder, ICompletedMailer>`:

```
public static void send(Function<IFromBuilder, ICompletedMailer> block) { 
    Mailer mailer = new Mailer();
    block.apply(mailer);
    System.out.println("sending..."); 
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this still allow the developer to do something like below, and there would be no compile time error for not including `to` or the other methods?
`Mailer.send(mailer -> mailer.from("from"));`
Would it even be possible to have that kind of functionality?